# Problem with ContentControl resizing

Tags: silverlight, resize

I've been hitting my head against a wall with this one for a while now.

I've got a custom control that derives from ContentControl - it's working perfectly EXCEPT that it won't resize to fit its parent, either declaratively OR programatically.

The custom control is parented within (ultimately) a content presenter, and that's correctly sized, but my control just will NOT size itself out to fit.

```
  (sample.MyControl) - 400x267
-  (System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter) - 979x569
```

Even when I explicitly set the width and height (at the right moment), the size doesn't "stick"

```
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("MyControl {0}: Size is {1}x{2} ({3}/{4})",
            GetHashCode(), this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight,
            this.HorizontalAlignment, this.VerticalAlignment));

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Parent is {0}x{1} ({2}/{3})",
                                      parent.ActualWidth, parent.ActualHeight, 
                                      parent.HorizontalAlignment, parent.VerticalAlignment));

        this.Width = parent.ActualWidth;
        this.Height = parent.ActualHeight;

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("MyControl {0}: New size is {1}x{2}",
            GetHashCode(), this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight));
```

The above code gives:

```
MyControl 36022757: Size is 400x267 (Stretch/Stretch)
Parent is 979x569 (Stretch/Stretch)
MyControl 36022757: New size is 400x267
```

Why! Oh Gods Why!

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need just to add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` and `VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to your control:

```
<ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    ...
</ContentControl>
```

In such cases [Silverlight Spy](http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/) tool can be helpful for debugging layout in runtime.

Try to run your application in this tool and you will be able to view all xaml elements and even change some properties in runtime.

Comment: Hmm I was hoping this would work for the same problem in WPF, though the fix doesn't appear to be changing anything. :(

Comment: I'd known about this all along - turns out that I needed to template out the container to apply these to the Content Control that was being wrapped around my control.